# Can Azure CloudServices (Web Role) be provisioned using ARM Template?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-resource-manager

Most of our application has been migrated to leverage Azure ARM Template but couple of web servers are still targetting Azure Cloud Services Web Roles. Unfortunately we're unable to upgrade these Cloud Services at the moment.

This is stopping our deployment to become fully automated using ARM Template based approach.

> Is there any workaround available to leverage ARM Template for Azure
>   cloud Services?

Comment: Note: In the "duplicate" question, the accepted answer is actually incorrect (as it's addressing web Apps). Look at the other answer. DL;DR there's no ARM support for Cloud Services; Cloud Services are only supported via the classic ASM API (not ARM).

Comment: well, there is no support, but they are perfectly deployable using arm apis @DavidMakogon and the question is not about the support, but about being able to deploy those

Comment: you can deploy those using arm templates

Comment: @DavidMakogon I do not see why scale set was recommended in other answer. in place of cloud services -- I do not see any correlation, we can't deploy cloud service packages to scalesets :-(

Comment: @Abhijeet - I don't know why scale sets are being promoted as a replacement, specifically. I'm just saying that the answer mentions the fact that ARM does not directly support deploying a Cloud Service.

Comment: he is not asking for support, he is asking a way to deploy those using arm, and that is perfectly possible @DavidMakogon

Comment: @4c74356b41 not sure why you keep replying to me multiple times. If you know how to do it, great - just post an answer on the other question.